# Temple run 2 multiplier calculation?

Tags: temple-run-2

In temple run, you can gain 59 multipliers in total. How are these multipliers calculated.

There are 44 objectives and 5 score multipliers abilities which should give 49 multiplier. If this is the case from where I get the rest 10 multiplier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, I have got the answer. The score multiplier go like this. When you upgrade it for the first time, it gives one multiplier. When you upgrade it second time, it gives two multipliers and so on. So 5 upgrades will give 15 multipliers in total.

Comment: Um, you should test this before answering.

Comment: @Meraj99 This is my test result.